# Cannot call method 'select2' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use the Select2 library to display a list of categories. I have a working regular `<select>` at the moment.

I added jquery, the stylesheet, the .js file and the function in my html.

```
<link href="/select2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="/select2/select2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { $("#listCategorie").select2(); });
</script>
```

However, the select is still displayed normally and I get the following error in console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'select2' of null

This is the select I have:

```
<select id="listCategorie">
    <option value="0"></option>
    ....
</select>
```

Comment: `$("#listCategorie")` is incorrect and returning null.

Comment: The select ID is set to listCategorie and it exists in my HTML. It should be able to find it since the function is called when the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Sorry, but that's what the error means.  Are you by chance running this locally, or on a webserver.  If locally, is it on localhost or running as a file (`file://`)?

Comment: It's running on a webserver

Comment: try with $("select").select2(); If it works then the problem is with your Id passed ..

Comment: I dont think there is any problem with `$("#listCategorie")` jquery doesn't return null even if the element matching the selector is not found. DO you have any `$` conflicts with any other libraries?

Comment: @AjinderSingh I've tried but same error

Comment: @oliboon try `jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery("#listCategorie").select2(); });`

Comment: @PSL As far as I can tell, the only libraries used are jQuery and Select2.

Comment: @oliboon jquery doesn't return null even if the element is not found... It will still return a jq object and you should not get this error.

Comment: @PSL This worked! If you can post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @PSL - You're right of course, I should have been clearer.  That's the normal error when jQuery returns an empty array and a plugin *expects* there to be at least 1 element.  jQuery returns `[]`, not null :)

Comment: @Archer Yes it doesn't return null, i believe `$` doesn't mean jquery in this case....

Comment: Yeah it would appear so.  Nicely done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have some conflicts with `$` and in your case `$` doesn't mean jQuery. Because jQuery doesn't return null even if the selector doesn't match any elements. Instead try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("#listCategorie").select2(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the ID of the element you are initializing `select2()` on is correct.
2. Check if the jquery and select2 libraries are loaded correctly by opening chrome developer console(<kbd>F12</kbd>) and go to sources / resources tab. See if your library is there.
3. Please post more code. It will be helpful in finding out the problem.

Comment: I've added my select with the corresponding ID. The resources are loaded correctly.

Comment: @oliboon I just copy pasted your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/geUMw/) and added your libraries. Things seem to work just fine. May the the error is somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need jQuery Migrate , because this plugin can have methods deprecated and then that's not gonna work with versions of jQuery 1.9 +

Comment: I've tried the jQuery Migrate but it still gives me the same error message.